# Ubuntu VM guest connected to VPN and tunneling access to VM host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have a TFS (Microsoft Team Foundation Server) available in my company's network through VPN connection. I can't connect directly to the VPN from my machine as it makes internet connection unavailable, so I wanted to check if this is possible: I thought about creating a VM guest that connects to the VPN, create a route or something like it (I just need port 8080), then in my Windows machine I can use the VM guest IP to tunnel the request.

Would it work? Is it possible?